# How to include snprintf without syscalls needed for printf?

Tags: c, io, embedded, printf

On an embedded platform, the syscalls needed for `printf` aren't usually available.  The standard solution is to write simple stubs e.g. for `_write`.

I don't need or want printf.  I need `snprintf` for internal string formatting. Is there any way to get that without having to stub out the syscalls, which will never be called anyway?

It seems backwards to have to write stubs for syscalls just to get internal string formatting routines.

---

## Update

If I `snprintf` a constant char buf, it links fine.  This is presumably because the compiler takes out `snprintf` and just uses `puts`.

But if I have a `"%d"` format string, I get linker errors.

Compile command (word wrapped for this post):

```
$ make flash -B
arm-none-eabi-gcc src/main.c -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror 
-Wundef -Wshadow -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat-truncation 
-Wconversion -Wno-attributes -DSTM32F446RE -DSTM32F446XX 
-DSTM32F4 -g3 -Os -fno-common -ffunction-sections 
-fdata-sections -fanalyzer -I. -I./libopencm3/include 
-MMD -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard 
-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16  -Tconfig/link.ld 
--static -nostartfiles -L./libopencm3/lib -lopencm3_stm32f4 
-Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--cref 
-Wl,-Map=firmware.map 
-o firmware.elf
```

Errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libg.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
/build/newlib-pB30de/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:51: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libg.a(lib_a-abort.o): in function `abort':
/build/newlib-pB30de/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/newlib/libc/stdlib/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:59: undefined reference to `_exit'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../
...
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libg.a(lib_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
/build/newlib-pB30de/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/readr.c:49: undefined reference to `_read'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd need to stub `_write` to get `snprintf()`. What is your platform / system? Does it (e.g. like default STM32 projects) remove unused symbols when it links?

Comment: for embedded targets, I would suggest writing your own simplified implementation.

Comment: What compiler are you using? If gcc you can compile with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` and link with `--gc-sections` and unused functions (and data) will not be included in the binary. So you wouldn't have to stub anything that wasn't needed.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Using gcc and those flags; updated post with details.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've always had problems with `snprintf()` on embedded systems. You'll get much more reliable behavior with `strtol()` and its relatives.

Comment: @B.Pantalone `strol` goes from `char[]` to `char[]`.  I need to go from `int` to `char`.

Comment: Did you consider to try the non-standard `itoa()`? -- The linker errors reveal that the `printf` family wants to allocate memory and needs the supporting functions. I'm afraid that you cannot have the one without the other.

Comment: Is it really so bad to have to implement empty do-nothing stubs for the unused syscalls?  That would take less time than you have spent on this question already.  Writing your own specialised integer to string routine is also trivial, and will result in much smaller code than linking all the necessary support for the more general stdio support.

Comment: This is in any case an X-Y problem.  You want to convert an `int` to a string, ask about that perhaps rather then how to make `snprintf` work - sledge-hammer to crack a nut.  Include in your question necessary constraints, such as not using specific library functions.  Newlib supports `itoa()` : https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#itoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a stand-alone version, that makes minimal or zero sys calls, and uses the stack so you don't have to worry about concurrency.

I've seen a `sprintf` & friends implementation in the past that doesn't call into the file system at all.

I'm using printf from the Arm mbed project. sprintf doesn't require IO per-se, but because printf is included you just have to provide a small stub: for `fpuctc`, `FILE` and `stdout`

My stubs are:

```c
struct io_stub_file
{
    int chanId;
    int (*putc_func)(int chan, char c);
    uint32_t flags; // you might not need this
    void (* pre_put_hook)(void); // you might not need this

typedef struct io_stub_file FILE;

};

extern struct io_stub_file * io_stub_ftab[];

#define stdout io_stub_ftab[1]
```

One problem with this, it will clash with <stdio.h> but you probably want to be avoiding that header anyway. It will inevitably drag in things from `reent.h` and such like, that it seems you build does not support.
Initialise the `stdout` entry so its `putc_func` drives your uart, or whatever you prefer to consider as `stdout`.

I would recommend against stubbing out things like `write` and `sbrk` because sooner or later, you will accidentally call on something in newlib that *requires these things to be functional*, then you'll be wondering why your standard library isn't working properly. If these things aren't functional then stay away from the parts of newlib that require them - if you accidentally call on them the linker errors will soon tell you, rather than it failing haphazardly.

Answer (score 0):

(Part of) the problem is that something wants abort, and abort calls printf (not just snprintf).

You can just stub out abort to prevent this.

It also looks like something wants malloc.  You might also want to stub out malloc if you have an embedded version, or else use the standard c library malloc but stub out _sbrk to tell it where to get the memory.